# Get names of all files in path

Tags: c#

I'm receiving an error **Access to the path ... is denied** when I attempt to read the files from a specified path.  The code that demonstrates the error is below:

```
string path = "D:\\Study\\Прога 4 семестр\\Курсач\\tests";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string s = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
}
sr.Close();
```

What exactly is wrong with the code that an error occurs?  How do I accomplish my goal?

Comment: You open a stream but never use it...?

Comment: Your are trying to open a stream to a folder, not a file.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get all files in directory, and then project each file path to file name:

```
var names = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
                     .Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f));
```

Or even shorter way:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension);
```

Comment: This requires .NET v4 or above to use `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: @BrianOliver yes, it does - its a new method, which enumerates file names without putting them to array. .NET v4 is here since 2010, so I believe its not a problem

Comment: Good point; I've just been burned before on those brownfield projects that can't for whatever reason be upgraded and are still running on older versions.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your using incorrect syntax.  `StreamReader` will read a file, it will not retrieve a file.  What you should do is use the `Directory` functionality from `System.IO`.

*Example:*

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach(string item in files)
     Console.WriteLine(item);
```

That would actually retrieve file data.

A secondary example:

```
 var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
 var file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
      .Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

The Microsoft Developer Network has some terrific articles on different approaches to handle retrieval of files or directories from the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.85).aspx) which has a method `GetFiles(String) (+ 2 overloads)` to enumerate and process files on older versions of .NET Frameworks.

```
string path = "D:\\Study\\Прога 4 семестр\\Курсач\\tests";
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path);
for(int i  = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path + "\\" + fileNames[i]);
    listBox1.Items.Add(fileName);
}
```